# Session only recognized after a $_GET or $_POST is set

Tags: php, session

Once I navigate away from my index.php page to let's say google.com and then back to my page's url, my session is recognized as unset.

Now after I either pass a variable through the URL or POST a form, my session will behave as is set.

I do have

```
session_start();
```

at the top of the page.

So again, now if I POST let's say a form my session will be set again. For example:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

}

<form method="POST" action="http://www.example.net">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing destroying the session when you leave the site?

Comment: Jay, thanks.  Let me look through the code and see if anything is destroying it, but the strange thing is that it would work after a POST from a form.

Comment: POSTing likely starts a new session.

Comment: I see nowhere where it is destroying the session.  And if that were the case, I would have to login again and doesn't explain why at POST or GET would re-create the session.

Comment: I feel like you're getting me in the right direction though so thanks.

Comment: thanks Jay for the help it was my browser blocking cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this actually ended up being my Google Chrome settings that were not allowing cookies to be used, because it worked with IE.

As per the PHP documentation:

*session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a      session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.*

So my browser was not allowing the cookies and the GET or POST method were how the session was getting started.  Hope this helps someone.